# How to search from a relational fields in Mongoose/MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

For Example, I have 2 Models one is Category and the other is Product. There has a one-to-many relationship.

The product has 3 fields. `name, price, category`
And also category has 3 fields. `name, description, products`

Here is the regular response of products.

```
[
        {
            "_id": "6353ce31f000d23c3e7a874c",
            "name": "Product 1",
            "price": 376,
            "category": "6353ce2af000d23c3e7a874a"
        },

       {...},
       {...},
       {...},
]
```

I can search by name or price in this way.

```
const options = {
  $or: [
          { name: new RegExp(searchText, 'i') },
          { price: new RegExp(searchText, 'i') }
       ],
}

Product.find(options)
```

Now my question is how can I search for products from categories fields?
If the search value matches the category `name or description` fields value it should return those products.

I'm using NestJs
Here is the GitHub Repo

https://github.com/hasibdev/nest-intro

You will get a `findAll` method inside `/src/modules/products/products.service.ts`

And for category
You will get a `findAll` method inside `/src/modules/categories/categories.service.ts`

Comment: You can use `$lookup` for this, to bring the categories into the product documents, or vice-versa.

Comment: @nimrodserok Could you please show me some code?

Comment: Please provide sample documents and the expected output from them, and I'll show you

Comment: @nimrodserok I've added the project GitHub repo with questions.

Comment: @nimrodserok You can make a pull request if you want to.